# How to call Application_Start() from TestInitialize method?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working with unit testing for an MVC application using Visual Studio's test project.
I need to call the `Application_start()` method from my `TestInitialise` unit test method, because `Application_Start()` initializes some global values that are required for my app.
I have also copied necessary info from `web.config` to `app.config` of my test app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to call the `Application_Start` method you will first need an instance of your application which is very difficult to have in a unit test. So externalize everything that you have in this method into a separate static method which you could invoke in your unit test.

Comment: Assuming I had an instance of my app, how would I call it? I guess I could easily make it public but I'm curious how it gets called in the first place